# Broadcast intent for mobile network change

Tags: android

I need to detect when the user has moved to a 3g network or 2G network or is in a no service area. Is there a standard android broadcast intent for that?

Currently im polling following code every minute in a service.

> TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)
>   getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>   if(tm.getNetworkType()==TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE){ }

But this is not a proper way, and can be bttery hungry. It would be better if it got triggered only by a listener or a brodcast intent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for intent `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` in OnRecieve you could do this.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    String typeName = info.getTypeName();
}
```

Edit:
You need to use the actual string in intent filter tag
 "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE". Also check this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

Comment: do u mean, i have to put `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`  in the manifest?

Comment: u mean, like this? ` <action android:name="ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />` ?
 It didnt work though. Also, theres no documenttion on this

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question.  I don't need to check internet connectivity.  I am looking for a broadcast intent which would occur if the user switches between 2g /3g network (irrespective of whether data is on), chooses another network from manual network selection,  or toggles flight mode.

Comment: i think when there is change in network, you get this intent, so you will have to check which network is switched. Statusbar uses this intent to swithc between E/H icon

Comment: I guess theres no E/H icon when theres no data connection.